# Ruby 1.8.7 converts 9,95 float to 994 int

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Weird..

```
$ (9.95*100).to_i
=> 994
```

And then,

```
$ (9.95*100).round.to_i
=> 995
```

It seems like the floating point value is (approximately) 9.9499999... and

```
to_i
```

chops the decimal value, hence the 994.

But does anyone know why?

Comment: welcome to the joys of floating point numbers, where everything is approximated and human expectations don't matter.

Comment: to_i is documented as truncating rather than rounding. what were you expecting?

Comment: I'll leave the usual link here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: `to_i` after `round` is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Read more about the problems with accuracy here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Short version: Never use floats as representation for currencies.

Comment: Or, even better, never use floating point without understanding its limitations.

Comment: @mcfinnigan: Why just floating-point? It is not okay to use integer arithmetic without understanding its limitations either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The limitations of integer arithmetic are generally a lot more obvious.  Integers work as expected until you run into overflow, and then stuff tends to go suddenly wrong.  Subtle rounding errors accumulated in, for e.g., a loop can take more time to notice and correct, as induction would lead people to believe that FP will work deterministically like integers - hence my statement.

Comment: @mcfinnigan: Although you say the limitations of integer arithmetic are obvious, people routinely overlook them. For example, Stack Overflow has numerous places where people advise to use integers for money without taking into account the fact that this fails for currency conversions, calculating unit prices in three-for-one-price deals, or calculating monthly interest from an annual rate. The advice should be to understand **whatever** you use, not to avoid floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to #round is rounding it "up" from (its internal representation of 9.95, which is a number slightly inaccurate and just below it).  So that one works, whereas calling straight #to_i just (always) truncates, so it sees 994.99999 and truncates it down to 994.  With Ruby 1.9.x+ it shows this more plainly (for better or worse), so you can see what is going on.

```
>> 9.95*100
=> 994.9999999999999
>> (9.95*100).round
=> 995
```